# CORS exception with Spring Data Rest + Spring Security when posting via '/login' path but other paths are fine

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-data-rest

Spring Boot 2.7.0
I faced CORS exception that triggered XMLHttpRequestError when trying to post via the '/login' path, other paths such as '/api/v1/members' are fine.

I followed the below guide,
https://github.com/amigoscode/spring-boot-security-course/tree/8-JTW

I am currently using SpringDataRest with configuration in RepositoryRestConfigurer as follow

```
@Component
class AppRepositoryRestConfigurer : RepositoryRestConfigurer { 
    override fun configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config: RepositoryRestConfiguration?, cors: CorsRegistry?) {
        cors?.addMapping("/**")?.allowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:[*]")
    }
}
```

Where else do I need to add CORS mapping in order to fulfil the post request via web. Right now posting via mobile app(iOS + Android) is ok with the Flutter framework, but Flutter Web is not ok.

I think the issue might be related to the OncePerRequestFilter? Below is my code from my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class AppWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    private val appUserDetailsService: AppUserDetailsService,
    private val jwtConfiguration: JwtConfiguration,
    private val secretKey: SecretKey,
    private val repository: MemberRepository
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) { 
        http {
            csrf {
                disable()
            }
            sessionManagement {
                sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
            }
            addFilterAt<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>(
                JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(
                    authenticationManager(),
                    jwtConfiguration,
                    secretKey,
                    repository
                )
            )
            addFilterAfter<JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter>(JwtTokenVerifier(jwtConfiguration, secretKey))
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize(anyRequest, permitAll)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder?) {
        auth?.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    fun daoAuthenticationProvider() =
        DaoAuthenticationProvider().apply {
            setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            setUserDetailsService(appUserDetailsService)
        }
}
```

My code for UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(
    authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    private val configuration: JwtConfiguration,
    private val secretKey: SecretKey,
    private val repository: MemberRepository
) : UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager) {

    private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
        registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    }

    override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?): Authentication {
        val authenticationRequest: UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest? =
            request?.inputStream?.let { jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(it) }
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest?.username, authenticationRequest?.password)
        )
    }
 
    override fun successfulAuthentication(
        request: HttpServletRequest?,
        response: HttpServletResponse?,
        chain: FilterChain?,
        authResult: Authentication?
    ) {
        val token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authResult?.name)
            .claim("authorities", authResult?.authorities)
            .setIssuedAt(Date())
            .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(configuration.daysToExpire)))
            .signWith(secretKey)
            .compact()
        val body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authResult?.name?.let(repository::findByEmail))
        response?.apply {
            addHeader(configuration.authorizationHeader, "${configuration.tokenPrefix} $token") 
            addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=utf-8")
            writer.write(body)
        }
    }
}
```

App.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Much help is appreciated:)

Comment: Any reason to why you are not using the built in JWTFilter that comes with spring security? And instead writing custom security which i might remind you is very bad practice. Why didnt you read the chapter on JWTs in the spring security documentation before asking here

Comment: i tried to set a custom jwt implementation because I tried to avoid setting the JwkUri https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-RC1/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#page-title

Comment: you dont need to set a jwkuri https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-RC1/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot also handing out JWTs to web browsers is a security risk, as they can be stolen, and not be revoked.

Comment: @Toerktumlare despite the fact that I am not using the JWTFilter provided by Spring Security, my own implementation of JWT is not wrong. This is a question that relates to CORS, not JWT implementation, you pointed me to the wrong direction to solve the problem. JWT security is another issue from my source code, but not solving the CORS exception mentioned in the question topic

Comment: I never claimed it to be the reason for your CORS. But having bad practice code can participate in all kinds of problems. Custom security IS bad practice you dont know that your implementation is wrong until someone pentests it. Spring security jwt impl is battle tested and fully tested and run in 1000s of apps, and you go ”i can do better because i read a tutorial” good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. This relates to the cors configuration in Spring Security. If you use web, the browser changed the POST request into an OPTIONS request, therefore blocked by the default CORS configuration because there default does not allow OPTION requests

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) { 
        http {
            csrf {
                disable()
            }
            cors {} //Enable CORS here
            sessionManagement {
                sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
            }
            addFilterAt<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>(
                JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(
                    authenticationManager(),
                    jwtConfiguration,
                    secretKey,
                    repository
                )
            )
            addFilterAfter<JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter>(JwtTokenVerifier(jwtConfiguration, secretKey))
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize(anyRequest, permitAll)
            }
        }
    }
```

Configure your CORS here

```
@Bean
fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
    val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
    configuration.allowedOrigins = listOf("https://example.com")
    configuration.allowedMethods = listOf("*") //Allow all http methods
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
    return source
}
```

This is no longer needed after implementing CORS in Spring Security

```
@Component
class AppRepositoryRestConfigurer : RepositoryRestConfigurer { 
    override fun configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config: RepositoryRestConfiguration?, cors: CorsRegistry?) {
        cors?.addMapping("/**")?.allowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:[*]")
    }
}
```